# Android: AIDL can't find Parcleable import class

Tags: java, android

Before I get besieged with "duplicate question" flags, I've [looked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14263005/aidl-unable-to-find-the-definition-of-a-parcelable-class) [at](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9277536/cant-use-aidl-files-across-library-projects) [the](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6360224/android-couldnt-find-import-for-class-java-util-arraylist-in-aidl-file) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17955094/aidl-interface-cant-find-import-for-parcelable-class) [to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6058350/android-couldnt-find-import-for-class-error-in-aidl-files-com-android-internal) [tons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24854980/android-aosp-compilation-error-cant-find-import-in-aidl-file) of questions, but none have helped me.

This is my AIDL file that defines my Parcleable object:

Position.aidl

```
package practice.parcey.second

parcelable Position;
```

And then my reporter:

MyServiceReporter.aidl

```
package practice.parcey.second;
import practice.parcey.second.Position;

interface MyServiceReporter {
    void report(List<Position> positions); 
}
```

*** for the below comments, underscores represent greater-than and less-than brackets, since this editor ignores them for some reason.

In that interface, if I change 'List_Position_' to 'int', everything compiles correctly. Of course, I don't want an 'int'.

Also, if I change "List_Position_" to "List_int_" it fails. This is perhaps the most curious part of all. And the compilation fails regardless of whether I include an import on java.util.list, such as:

```
package practice.parcey.second;
import practice.parcey.second.Position;
import java.util.List;

interface MyServiceReporter {
    void report(List<int> positions); 
}
```

In every case, I get the same lovely error message:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugAidl'.
>
> > java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error while executing
> >     process C:\Android\sdk\build-tools\25.0.3\aidl.exe with arguments
> >     {-pC:\Android\sdk\platforms\android-26\framework.aidl
> >     .......

Comment: does `List<String>` work?

Comment: No, but naked String works

Comment: make it `in List<Position> position`

Comment: or out or inout

Comment: Wow the "in" keyword fixed it -- what a filthy little bug!

Comment: and you would catch that little beast if you clicked on "gradle console" tab on the bottom of android studio ;-) and yes, i agree it should not be hidden so...